# Integral $\int_0^{2\pi} \sqrt{A^2-\frac{B^2}{\sin^2x}} dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, quantum-mechanics

This is the integral obtained when finding the energy level of a hydrogen atom by Sommerfeld quantization. How to evaluate this integral?
$$\int_0^{2\pi}\sqrt{A^2-\frac{B^2}{\sin^2\theta}}d\theta$$
Thank you.

Comment: This integral isn't defined, as at multiple intervals  the inside of the square root will be negative.

Comment: Please share a reference for this, my curiosity is piqued.

Comment: Looking back at this, I think your confusion lies in a misunderstanding of Sommerfield quantization. The quantization scheme only integrates over periodic motion, but the motion is closed in *phase* space- that is $\theta(t)$, should you solve the dynamics of the system, would be a periodic function of $t\in\Bbb{R}$. But the configuration of the embedding in phase space (the elimination of the parameter) need not be a periodic function, only a path connected structure (possibly with turning points). The bounds of your integral correspondingly should be fixed from some min $a$ to some max $b$

Answer (score 1):

Computing the antiderivative$$I=\int\sqrt{A^2-\frac{B^2}{\sin^2(x)}}\,dx$$ is not so bad.

Let
$$x=\cot ^{-1}(t) \qquad \text{and} \qquad  C^2=\frac {A^2-B^2}{B^2}$$

$$I=-B\int \frac{\sqrt{C^2-t ^2}}{t^2+1}\,dt$$
$$t=C\sin(u)\qquad \implies \qquad I=-B C^2 \int \frac{\cos ^2(u)}{1+C^2 \sin ^2(u)}\,du$$
$$u=\tan^{-1}(v)\qquad \implies \qquad I=-B C^2 \int \frac{dv}{\left(v^2+1\right) \left(\left(C^2+1\right) v^2+1\right)}$$ Now, partial fraction decomposition would lead to two arctangents.